# execution of open3 failed due to unknown errors

Tags: perl

I am trying to use open 3 something like below but it fails with below error

```
    0:[/home/gangg/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/bin/java]
1:[ -cp ]
2:[/scratch/agentHome/osbssl/plugins/oracle.sysman.emas.agent.plugin_12.1.0.4.0/archives/em-pp-osbProv-pojo.jar:/scratch/gangg/wls1036/middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/scratch/gangg/wls1036/middleware/Oracle_OSB1/lib/sb-kernel-api.jar:/scratch/gangg/wls1036/middleware/Oracle_OSB1/lib/sb-kernel-impl.jar:/scratch/gangg/wls1036/middleware/Oracle_OSB1/modules/com.bea.common.configfwk_1.6.0.0.jar]
3:[ -Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=/scratch/agentHome/osbssl/agent_inst/sysman/config/montrust/AgentTrust.jks]
4:[oracle.sysman.pp.osbprov.util.OSBResourceImportUtil]
5:[/scratch/agentHome/osbssl/core/12.1.0.3.0/EMStage/PAF/osbprov/A051D1BF44FC91B2B624B08B21932FD6_1367241748834/target_/Farm02_base_domain/base_domain/HelloWorld.jar]
6:[test.com]
7:[7771]
8:[weblogic]
9:[true]
10:[true]
11:[true]
12:[true]
13:[true]
14:[null]
15:[11.1.1.6]
16:[t3s]

     $pid = open3( \*HANDLE_IN, \*HANDLE_OUT, \*HANDLE_ERR, @args);

 open3: exec of /home/gangg/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/bin/java -cp /scratch/agentHome/osbssl/plugins/oracle.sysman.emas.agent.plugin_12.1.0.4.0/archives/em-pp-osbProv-pojo.jar:/scratch/gangg/wls1036/middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/scratch/gangg/wls1036/middleware/Oracle_OSB1/lib/sb-kernel-api.jar:/scratch/gangg/wls1036/middleware/Oracle_OSB1/lib/sb-kernel-impl.jar:/scratch/gangg/wls1036/middleware/Oracle_OSB1/modules/com.bea.common.configfwk_1.6.0.0.jar
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=/scratch/agentHome/osbssl/agent_inst/sysman/config/montrust/AgentTrust.jks abc.xyz.OSBResourceImportUtil /scratch/agentHome/osbssl/core/12.1.0.3.0/EMStage/PAF/osbprov/A051D1BF44FC91B2B624B08B21932FD6_1367231855615/target_/Farm02_base_domain/base_domain/HelloWorld.jar test.xyz.com 7771 weblogic true true true true true null 11.1.1.6 t3s failed at 
 /tmp/JOB_DB7E7A13B78883EAE040E80A57827806/deploy.pl line 157
```

Comment: I directly executed the command in java but it executed fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a `perl` issue, I think. The `java` code failed. Run it manually with the same command line and check the return value and see what is printed to the screen.

I checked the issue a little bit. If the called java code returns an exception then `open3` returns the `pid` and the stderr can be read. If the name of the `java` code is wrong then `java` also returns an exception, so stderr can be read. But if the java interpreter's path is wrong then one can get the following `perl` error message:

```
open3: exec of gijx -cp . a x failed at ./a.pl line 8
```

So I assume the path to `java` (I use `gij` instead of `java`) is not correct or the `perl` script has no permission to run it.

Comment: I directly executed the command in java but it executed fine

Comment: @constantlearner: `Perl` is executed with the same user as You tried directly? I assume that it is some problem launching the java executable. If it could be started it wouldn't produce this error message. It also can be that some of the args (like the `-cp` is in the first element of `@args`. Could You print the values in args one-by-one? `@args` should contain one element holding the complete command line or every command line element in a separate field. It cannot be mixed.

Comment: I have updated the argument array

Comment: @constantlearner: the problem is that it cannot be seen what are the individual elements. Please try something like this: `for (my $i=0;$i<=$#args;++$i) {print "$i:[$args[$i]]\n"};`.

Comment: @constantlearner: and there it is! See the first (actually 0th) element! As I assumed the program name is not `/path/java` but `/path/java -cp `. And there is not such file! Put the `-cp` to another `@args` element!

Comment: I am getting noclassdef found error ...Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  -cp 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  -cp 
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class:  -cp .  Program will exit.

Comment: @constantlearner: Of course it does not work! You defined a `_-cp_` argument instead of `-cp` (I marked space as `_`)! Remove the spaces around `-cp`! I do not know but in the 3rd element of `@args` You could have similar problem! Remove the space and I assume that the `-D` argument should be in a different array item then the following path.

Comment: I did that Thanks for your help now diffrent issue i am getting diffrent exception Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  -Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=.scratch.agentHome.osbssl.agent_inst.sysman.config.montrust.AgentTrust.jks

Comment: When i print it says but how it get converted to . instead of / after open3 AGENT_KEYSTORE_LOC: /scratch/agentHome/osbssl/agent_inst/sysman/config/montrust/AgentTrust.jks

Comment: @constantlearner: see the end of my previous comment about `-D`! Remove the space before!

Comment: Thanks TrueY thanks for your patience I am new to perl learning now.Appreciate your help.Its solved ...

Comment: @constantlearner: I'm happy if I could help! It is not really `perl` issue, rather understanding how the shell interprets the command line.